# How to Get the Supervisor's Name instead of the UserID + INNER JOIN in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Here are my tables :

> select * from user

```
USERID  NAME    STATUS
1       AAA     Member
2       BBB     Member
3       CCC     Supervisor
4       DDD     Member
5       EEE     Member
```

> select * from attendance

```
NO  DATE        SUPERVISOR  MEMBER
1   2019-12-11  3           1
2   2019-12-11  3           2
3   2019-12-11  3           4
4   2019-12-11  3           5
```

> select * from detail

```
NO  USERID  ATTENDANCE  REASON
1   1       0           SICK
2   2       1           -
3   4       1           -
4   5       1           -
```

The result I want :

```
USERID  DATE        NAME    REASON  SUPERVISOR
1       2019-12-11  AAA     SICK    CCC
2       2019-12-11  BBB     -       CCC
3       2019-12-11  DDD     -       CCC
4       2019-12-11  EEE     -       CCC
```

The SQL I've tried calls the supervisor's userid instead of the name of the supervisor.

```
SELECT d.userid, a.date, u.name, d.reason, a.supervisor FROM attendance a INNER JOIN detail d on a.userid = d.userid INNER JOIN user u on d.userid = u.userid WHERE d.attendance=0
```

I need help with the sql to call the supervisor's name not the userid.
Thanks..

Comment: Do you have a `userid` column in table `attendance`? or `no` is `userid`?

Comment: It's useful when constructing these kinds of examples, to use different scales of units for different things, so userids might be 11,12,13,14, and 'nos' might be 101,102,103, etc. It tends to aid clarity.

Comment: @Sarques There is, the `Member` field

Answer (score 1):

You have to join the user table twice because you are matching it for both the member name and the supervisor name. I also used `LEFT JOIN` because sometimes the reason does not have a value but you still want to pull the records from the other tables.

```sql
SELECT u1.userid, a.date, u1.name, d.reason, u2.name AS supervisor
FROM user u1
LEFT JOIN attendance a ON u1.userid = a.member
LEFT JOIN detail d ON u1.userid = d.userid
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON a.supervisor = u2.userid
WHERE d.attendance = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT u1.userid, a.date, u1.name As Name, d.reason, u2.name AS supervisor
FROM user u1
LEFT JOIN attendance a ON u1.userid = a.member
LEFT JOIN detail d ON u1.userid = d.userid
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON a.supervisor = u2.userid
WHERE d.attendance=0;
```